# Database solution for music player application written in Qt

Tags: qt

I am creating a music player in Qt (c++) that has music library implementation like itunes'. The application will need to store data in forms of SQL tables. Qt has an inbuilt SQL library. So let's say I use MySQL here. but I'm afraid, in each and every system where I install my music player, I will have to make sure MySQL is preinstalled.

I'm newbie in Qt. Any kind of help/advice would be awesome!

Comment: Go with "QSQLITE" if you don't need it to be run in a network/distributed environment.  If you're just starting off then it'll probably also be a pain to get the SQL drivers set up for Qt as it's not provided by default.

Comment: Yep here is the information you need:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/sql-driver.html#qsqlite